# Getting Could not resolve com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0. error while gradle build

Tags: android

I need some help for integrating library.
I'm getting following error while compiling android project:
Could not resolve com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0.

Following is detailed files:

Top-level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

project build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.+'
}
```

stack trace

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
Could not resolve com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0.
Required by:
STYYLE:app:unspecified
> Could not resolve com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/v1.0/Custom-Calendar-View-v1.0.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/v1.0/Custom-Calendar-View-v1.0.pom'.
> RSA premaster secret error
> Could not resolve com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/v1.0/Custom-Calendar-View-v1.0.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/v1.0/Custom-Calendar-View-v1.0.pom'.
> RSA premaster secret error
> Could not resolve com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/v1.0/Custom-Calendar-View-v1.0.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/npanigrahy/Custom-Calendar-View/v1.0/Custom-Calendar-View-v1.0.pom'.
> RSA premaster secret error
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to invalidate caches, restart, and then sync again. It should work. I checked right now library is working.

Comment: I tried doing this, but still same error persist. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, issue was JDK android studio was using.
After changing it to embedded JDK in project settings,error was gone.